# Unable to update or uninstall LiveWare

Tags: updates, sony-xperia-arc

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S, and I am unable to update or uninstall LiveWare.

Every time I try to update, a message pops up saying:

> Error package file was not signed correctly. Uninstall the previous copy of the app and try again.

However, I am unable to uninstall it as there is no option for me to do so, only the option to update. I also cannot open LiveWare, and because I can not update it my SmartWatch is not working properly as I am unable to install apps to the watch.

My phone is up to date as I have downloaded the latest updates to 4.0.3

I have reset my phone to factory settings updated it and done everything I can think of. What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall LiveWare™ manager or Smart Connect

1. From your phone’s main application menu, find and tap **Settings** > **Applications**.
2. Select **LiveWare™ manager** or **Smart Connect**.
3. Tap **Uninstall**, then tap **OK**.
4. Install **LiveWare™ manager** or **Smart Connect** application from Google Play™ again.

***Note**: The Smart Connect application only works for Sony phones running Android™ version 4.0 and later. All other Android™ phones still need LiveWare™ manager application.*

([Source](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/support/faq/smartwatch/smartwatch/how-do-i-reinstall-liveware-manager-on-my-android-phone-4/))